# Are Warforged PCs affected by healing differently than other PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, unearthed-arcana, warforged

I have a player who just created a warforged barbarian. The [2015 Unearthed Arcana on Eberron](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.pdf) brought warforged and artificers but didn't mention how they are healed. Is he stuck with half healing from regular spells? Should I introduce warforged tools since there is no craft skill?
Ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**As of 5e's published release and the Unearthed Arcana article, Warforged are treated no differently than PCs of other races.**

Since it does not mention any healing exceptions for warforged in the Unearthed Arcana article that introduces them to 5e; they should have any and all healing effects work on them as per usual.

*2018 update (thanks @Trevel)*

---

This question has now been explicitly answered in the Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron, under [the description of the warforged's composition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/warforged#LivingSteelandStone) (p. 67):

> While they’re formed from stone and steel, warforged are living
>   humanoids. Resting, healing magic, and the Medicine skill all provide
>   the same benefits to warforged that they do to other humanoids.

Answer (score 13):

This question has now been explicitly answered in the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, under [the description of the warforged's composition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/warforged#LivingSteelandStone) (p. 67):

> While they’re formed from stone and steel, warforged are living
>   humanoids. Resting, healing magic, and the Medicine skill all provide
>   the same benefits to warforged that they do to other humanoids.

Comment: The relevant wording in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* is slightly different, but fundamentally the same: "**Although they were manufactured**, warforged are living humanoids. Resting, healing magic, and the Medicine skill all provide the same benefits to warforged that they do to other humanoids."

Answer (score 12):

## Warforged can be healed using healing spells such as Cure Wounds, according to the designer's intent.

Mike Mearls said as much regarding the Warforged race in Unearthed Arcana for 5e when somebody asked him about it on Twitter (see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/789114462884073472)):

> **Question:** Can a Warforged be healed through spells like Cure Wounds?
>
> **Answer:** Yes.

Since Unearthed Arcana is not part of the standard game rules for 5e, there are no *official* rulings on its content per se. However, since Mearls is the designer for the content, this quote makes the intended interpretation unambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to remind everyone that in the description of a Warforged it literally states "Although they are ***constructs***, they have much in common with living creatures, including emotions and social bonds, and perhaps even souls" And healing spells such as cure wounds state "This spell has no effect on undead or constructs." so according to the D&D 5e rules, warforged cannot be healed by spells such as that.

You can find this on page 3 of the Unearthed Arcana: Eberron Setting for the warforged description and page 230 in the Player's Handbook for 5th edition for the spell Cure Wounds.

Link: http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/unearthed-arcana-eberron

Posted by Wizards of the Coast

Comment: Hey @NathanCholewinski welcome to RPG.SE take the [tour] to learn more about our community. Your answer could be improved by providing a link or a page reference.

Answer (score 1):

The *cure wounds* spell states "A creature you touch…" (Basic Rules v0.2, page 86).

The UA article states "Living Construct. Even though you were constructed, you are a living creature."

If the DM rules that a warforged is not a "creature" then you can happily conclude that your warforged is immune to *fireball* and *disintegrate* and so on. :-)

My conclusion is that cure spells and healers' kits work on a Warforged.

Note that the potion of healing says "A character who drinks…" (Basic Rules v0.2, page 50) so they certainly work on a Warforged.

Comment: Whether the spell uses "creature" is unimportant, here. Cure Wounds explicitly says, "This spell has no effect on undead or constructs." Unearthed Arcana clearly states that warforged are constructs but does not indicate whether they are excluded by healing spells and effects.

Answer (score -1):

It's stated that the wooden parts of a warforged are organic as in a living creature; so the healing affects a warforged like a creature.

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to add the source @Simo for this answer?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As mentioned, you should support your answer by citing the source. Also, note that the original question was about the version from the very first UA: Eberron in 2015; other existing answers have also pointed out that the version in WGtE does explicitly say healing magic works normally.