# Which healing methods work on Nimblewright player characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, constructs

[Mirt's Undermountain Survival Guide](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/269024/Mirts-Undermountain-Survival-Guide?filters=45680) contains a new playable race: the Nimblewright. Amongst other things, it is a construct rather than a humanoid.

Several healing methods in the game, such as the Cure Wounds spell, have an anti-construct clause:

> This spell has no effect on Undead or constructs.

I was not able to find the list of healing methods that do not have this clause (either on this site or elsewhere), and it would help me to get it, as I am soon to start DMing a Campaign where one of the players will play a Nimblewright character (in Adventurers league play, thanks to a special certificate acquired by donating to [Travis Woodall's Extra Life Charity page](https://www.extra-life.org/index.cfm?fuseaction=donorDrive.participant&participantID=370463)).

**Which healing methods work on Nimblewright player characters?**

Comment: Related: "[Can the warforged from UA: Eberron benefit from healing spells and the Medicine skill?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74266)", "[Are Warforged PCs affected by healing differently than other PCs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58063)", "[Are warforged PCs affected by Mirror of Life Trapping and other spells/abilities that don't affect constructs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151957)", "[Can Constructs use magical potions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127519)"

Comment: Hi GaelL! I just wanted to jump in here and let you know that you only heard half of that user's comment (they didn't have the chance to say the other half), but certainly nobody here is saying you are in any way a bad person. Nor, honestly, is it a bad question IMO. In fact, several users think it is useful enough they have already voted to undelete it. Please feel free to reach out to me or any other mods or members if you are having any issues that we can help you out with. :)

Comment: I seem to recall a Nimblewright NPC or monster in the *Waterdeep Dragon Heist* published adventure.  Is this the same as that, or something else?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm not sure if it's the same ([this](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/nimblewright)) but the monster does have the Repairable feature where the *mending* cantrip restores 1 hit point per casting (if the creature has 1 or more hit points remaining)

Comment: Might a tighter scope to this question be "which healing methods will not work?" or does that face you with the same problem?

Answer (score 7):

**Healing Spells :**

- [Goodberry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Goodberry)
- [Aura of Vitality](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Aura-of-Vitality)
- [Life transference](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Life-transference)
- [Revivify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Revivify)
- [Vampiric Touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Vampiric-Touch)
- [Aura of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Aura-of-Life)
- [Enervation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Enervation)
- [Raise Dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Raise-Dead)
- [Soul Cage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Soul-Cage)
- [Regenerate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Regenerate)
- [Resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Resurrection)
- [True Resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/True-Resurrection)
- Wish (stressful)

**Healing Magic items :**

- Potion of Healing
- Potion of Greater Healing
- Potion of Superior Healing
- Potion of Supreme Healing
- Potion of Vitality (indirectly)
- Periapt of Wound Closure (indirectly)
- Ring of regeneration
- Ioun Stone of Regeneration
- Rod of Security
- Keoghtom's Ointment

**Other Healing abilities :**

- Hit Dice and Long resting
- A Bard's Song of Rest
- A Life Cleric's Blessed Healer
- A Fighter's Second Wind
- An Open Hand Monk's Wholeness of Body
- A Necromancer Wizard's Grim Harvest
- A Purple Dragon Knight Fighter's Rallying Cry
- A Crown Paladin's Turn the Tide
- A Dreams Druid's Balm of the Summer Court
- A Sheperd Druid's Unicorn Spirit
- A Redemption Paladin's Protective Spirit
- A Celestial Warlock's Healing Light
- An Aasimar's Healing Hands

The list is currently not exhaustive. I am attempting to expand it by doing more research.