# How to heal a shield guardian?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, constructs

The [shield guardian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shield-guardian) has a creature type of "construct".  While the shield guardian is able to regenerate hit points, that may be insufficient to keep one on its feet in combat, so additional healing might be useful.  Certain types of healing, for instance, the [*cure wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds) spell, specifically say "has no effect on constructs".  It seems logical, then, that any other method of restoring hit points, for instance, the [*potion of healing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-healing), that does not contain such a restriction, would be able to heal a shield guardian.  I can find no rule that contradicts this.  It seems then, that how to heal a shield guardian is to use any healing that doesn't exclude constructs.  Is this the correct interpretation of the rules?

Comment: I assume you're interested in rapid in-combat healing, or the case for constructs generically, as the shield guardian has Regeneration.

Comment: Yeah, I'm interested without regard to regeneration.  Sure, the SG can go from 1 to 142 HP in 150 seconds, but that's a long long time when the beholder is cutting loose with the disintegration all the time.

Comment: Related: [Which healing methods work on Nimblewright player characters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/156510/47185)

Comment: @RedOrca, about laying on of hands, you are right!  I must have missed that last paragraph.

Comment: You may want to add a note for clarity that you are talking about *in combat* healing only since the Shield Guardian would always be at full health outside of combat.

Comment: Edited to clarify about in-combat healing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## You are correct.

If any healing spell, item, effect, or feature does not specifically exclude constructs, and the construct lacks features that prevent healing magic from restoring its HP, then it will heal a *shield guardian*.

Answer (score -1):

## Let it take a nap.

You are correct that any healing that does not specifically exclude constructs the way *cure wounds* does. Turn on your *aura of vitality*, mash some *goodberries* into its face, or just tell it to take a short rest so it can spend some of its hit dice.

Comment: If you're outside of combat, the Shield Guardian is automatically at full health since it regains 10 hit points every six seconds. There is literally no circumstance where a shield guardian does not have full health at the completion of a short rest.